# How to select distinct rows from a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a table named 'versions' which has columns control_no, revision_id ,revision_dt, version_no, version_dt, created_by, change_type, summary, new_owner.

Each control_no has revision_id ranging from 1 to a specific number. From this table, I want to select 
VERSION_NO,CHANGE_TYPE,SUMMARY,CREATED_BY for a CONTROL_NO with max(REVISION_ID).

How to do this?

Comment: Just listing some column names is not really enough for us to understand your problem. Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: please clear your question  if you  wants to use the max revision_id for each control_no???

Comment: Hi. This is a(n obvious) faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do need to ask a code question please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query

```
select VERSION_NO,CHANGE_TYPE,SUMMARY,CREATED_BY from VERSIONS where REVISION_ID in (SELECT A.REVISION_LIST FROM (select max(REVISION_ID) AS REVISION_LIST, CONTROL_NO AS CONT_NO from VERSIONS GROUP BY CONTROL_NO)A);
```

Answer (score 0):

By Below Code you can get

```
SELECT MAX(Version_id) AS Version_id, VERSION_NO,CHANGE_TYPE,SUMMARY,CREATED_By, CONTROL_NO 
from table
GROUP BY VERSION_NO,CHANGE_TYPE,SUMMARY,CREATED_By, CONTROL_NO
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
 select VERSION_NO,CHANGE_TYPE,SUMMARY,CREATED_BY,max(REVISION_ID),control_no 
  from versions group by control_no;
```

Comment: I think @aiswarya wants to use the max `revision_id` for each `control_no`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson now its ok??